# How to plot actual vs. predicted values with a confidence interval on time series graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some difficulties to nicely (gg)plot actual vs. predicted values.

Here some data:

```
# I use caret in order to split the data into train and test
library(caret)
data(economics) # from caret
library(forecast)
# that is recommended for time series data
timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(economics), 
                       initialWindow = 36, horizon = 10, fixedWindow = TRUE)

 trainSlices <- timeSlices[[1]]
 testSlices <- timeSlices[[2]]

# I'm not really sure about the periods
fit <- tbats(economics[trainSlices[[1]],]$unemploy, seasonal.periods=c(4,12), use.trend=TRUE, use.parallel=TRUE)

# Using forecast for prediction
pred <- forecast(fit,h=length(economics[testSlices[[1]],]$unemploy))
# Here I plot the forecast
plot(pred)
```

[image]

Here I just actually stuck and dont really know how to add the test data aka testSlices to that particular pred object with the corresponding test/train labels. Perhaps there is also a way to use a different style on the confidence interval.
Thank you!

Comment: From which package `economics` comes from?

Comment: Hi its from the `caret` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is definitely cleaner way of doing it.

Fast way to do it, is like this:

```
lines(x = as.numeric(rownames(economics[testSlices[[1]],])), economics[testSlices[[1]],]$unemploy, col = "red")
```

**Update for comment:**

Add labels:

```
legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("Predicted", "Test Data"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you JavK. Is there a way to label train and test slices?

Comment: Add this: 
legend(x = "topleft", legend = c("Predicted", "Test Data"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = c(1, 1))